# PWA Notification

Tags: notifications, progressive-web-apps

I've added notifications to my PWA app and i'm facing a question I can't find an answer. Is there a way to hide the source of the notification? (the line between the title and the body, saying where the notification came from)? Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you provide more info, screenshot and your code sample.

Answer (score 2):

Browser vendors don't let developers remove site information from notifications for security and auditing purposes. They want to ensure that if a bad site is abusing notifications, users can easily identify the site and block them.